# How to use distinct with group by in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert the following sql to Linq 2 SQL:

```
select groupId, count(distinct(userId)) from processroundissueinstance 
group by groupId
```

Here is my code:

```
var q = from i in ProcessRoundIssueInstance
    group i by i.GroupID into g
    select new
    {
        Key = g.Key,
        Count = g.Select(x => x.UserID).Distinct().Count()
    };
```

When I run the code, I keep getting Invalid GroupID. 
Any ideas? Seems the distinct is screwing things up..

Here is the generated sql:

```
SELECT [t1].[GroupID] AS [Key], (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t2].[UserID]
    FROM [ProcessRoundIssueInstance] AS [t2]
    WHERE (([t1].[GroupID] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[GroupID] IS NULL)) 
       OR (([t1].[GroupID] IS NOT NULL) 
            AND ([t2].[GroupID] IS NOT NULL) 
            AND ([t1].[GroupID] = [t2].[GroupID]))
    ) AS [t3]
) AS [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[GroupID]
    FROM [ProcessRoundIssueInstance] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[GroupID]
    ) AS [t1]
```

Comment: @Basiclife: What's FUBAR about that? In SQL NULL is not equal to anything, including NULL. If both were NULL, `t1.GroupID = t2.GroupId` would still be false. That's that only way to associate two NULL fields.

Answer (score 5):

I think Basiclife is close, but checking if the id is empty may not be the issue or enough, you should check to make sure it is not null before doing the group since you said it is a nullable field.  Otherwise it looks right, and if you are having issues you may have bad data, or it is a bug or not fully implemented feature of Linq to SQL, and you may want to try Linq to Entity.

```
var q = from i in ProcessRoundIssueInstance
        where i.GroupID != null
        && i.GroupID != string.Empty
        group i by i.GroupID into g        
        select new
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Count = g.Select(x => x.UserID).Distinct().Count()
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, your code looks correct:

[LINQ to SQL using GROUP BY and COUNT(DISTINCT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448203/linq-to-sql-using-group-by-and-countdistinct)

Have you tried inspecting the SQL that is generated?

Comment: Yes, please look at my original post to see the invalid sql generated.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a whole bunch of goop in the generated SQL to deal with the GroupID being NULL.   If that a possiblity?  IF not, try changing the definition to make it NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try a where clause to eliminate spurious Ids after the join...

```
var q = from i in ProcessRoundIssueInstance
    where i.GroupID != ""
    group i by i.GroupID into g
    select new
    {
        Key = g.Key,
        Count = g.Select(x => x.UserID).Distinct().Count()
    };
```

Comment: Out of interest, is there any Id column nullable intentionally? Also, can you tell us the data type for ProcessRoundIssueInstance according to the debugger (not declaration). Thanks

Comment: Yes, the GroupID is nullable but I also tried on another non-nullable column. System.Data.Linq.Table<ProcessRoundIssueInstance>

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain of correct database integrity? Anyway maybe you should try this:
I don't know how a group would be empty, but that seems to be your problem.

```
ProcessRoundIssueInstance.Where(i => i.GroupId != null)
    .GroupBy(i => i.GroupID)
    .Select(group => new 
                    { 
                      Key = group.Key,
                      Count = group.SingleOrDefault() == null ? 0 : 
                              group.SingleOrDefault().Select( item => item.UserID).Distinct().Count() 
                     });
```