# not able to get the number of products count

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have product table with columns

```
 product_id (p.k)
 product_name
 product_description
 product_price
 category_id
```

and I have set the properties for `product_id` like this...(primary key , not null,A.I)

I am trying to represent the number of same  products in datagrid view as a column like this

```
product_name     product_description         stock available        product price

    a                good product                2  (a+a)                  300

    b                bad product                 3   (b+b+b)                  400
```

by the following method....

```
var stockavailable = dbcontext.products
   .GroupBy(x => x.product_Id)
   .Select(a => new
                {
                    productid = a.Key,
                    productnam = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Name,
                    productdescr = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Description,
                    stockavailable = a.LongCount(),
                    productprice = a.FirstOrDefault().product_Price
                });

bindingsource.DataSource = stockavailable;
datagridview1.DataSource = bindingsource;
```

But it does not show the number of products even if there are two same products. with different product_id 's would any one pls help on this...

**EDIT :**
             Can i do like this.....

```
  stockavailable = a.select(x=>x.product_id).Distinct().Count() 
    Instead of this stockavailable = a.LongCount(),
```

Comment: would any one pls help me on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `product_id` is the primary key, then wouldn't it be distinct for every entry? No 2 rows would have the same `product_id`, right? If that is true, then `GroupBy(x => x.product_id)` won't do any real grouping. Every row will be its own group.

I think what you want is something closer to:

```
var stockavailable = dbcontext.products
   .GroupBy(x => new {x.product_Name, x.product_Description, x.product_Price })
   .Select(a => new
                {
                    productnam = a.Key.product_Name,
                    productdescr = a.Key.product_Description,
                    stockavailable = a.LongCount(),
                    productprice = a.Key().product_Price
                });
```

Also, wouldn't it have been easier to just add a `product_Quantity` column? The way your table is set up now, couldn't you have:

```
id  |  name  |  desc  |  price
1      a        good     350
2      a        good     300
3      b        bad      400
```

So there are 2 of the same product with different prices.

Comment: Many thanks.. but this is not what i am asking ..... i need to represent the datagrid view with products avaialable (stock available).....number of products who have with same  Name.... like i have mentioned sample datagrid view in my question....

Comment: I don't think anyone knows what it is you actually want then. Can you express what you want as a regular SQL query? If you want things grouped by the same product_name, then just change the grouping I provided to `.GroupBy(x.product_name)` instead.

Comment: I have already specified in my question(sample datagrid view) i want exactly same like that....

Comment: Which is exactly (i think) what I gave you... you should be grouping by `Product_Name` not `Product_Id`.  I don't understand how my and Davide's answers aren't working for you.  What DO you get when you try either of our solutions, and how is that different from what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

what you are missing is to do a count on number of rows with same `product_id`

In SQL after you do a group by you can use aggregate functions like sum, count, max, min and so on, in your case you do a group by but forgot to insert a count.

see here this very similar question for syntax on how to use the count in LINQ:

[LINQ to SQL using GROUP BY and COUNT(DISTINCT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448203/linq-to-sql-using-group-by-and-countdistinct)