# Group by in a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of objects like this:

```
BonusesToApprove = new List<Bonus>();
```

I need to group it by id. I've tried several approaches like [the suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812629/group-by-in-a-liststring) but the compiler returns message:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<AdHoc.Objects.Bonus> does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' ...
```

A sample of the code I've tried is:

```
var grouped = BonusesToApprove
    .GroupBy ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you need to do with the `GroupBy`?

Comment: `but the compiler does not like it`. That is very explanatory :)

Comment: Group by id : `.GroupBy(t=>t.id)` - but do you really need to group by ID? Usually ID is unique, so you will have a lot of groups with a single member..

Comment: when I do this: var grouped = BonusesToApprove.GroupBy(t => t.id); I get System.Collections.Generic.List<AdHoc.Objects.Bonus> does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' ...

Comment: Post the code for your `Bonus` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have forgotten to reference the LINQ namespace in your class.

Put this at the top with any other `using` statements you have:

```
using System.Linq;
```