# C#: Counting Multiples in a List

Tags: c#, list, enums, count

So the issue I'm running into is I'm wanting to count the multiples of an enum within a list. Say, for example, I have a List of "Hi" "Hi" "Hello" "Hi" and "Hello".

Is there a way in which I can search the array and find out that there is 3 of the "Hi" without having to do the List.Where x = "Hi">?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: And then what about "Hello"? Are you going to test that too? Please post your c# code.

Comment: I would like to find out if "Hello" has multiples too. From what I've found online, and my basic knowledge of c# I've only seen the .Where<> capabilities however I have to predefine what enum or string I'm trying to find in the list. I'm wondering if there was a way to have it just count the enums or strings themselves and return their are multiples.

Comment: So you want a resulting list that contains only enums that are mutiples ??

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? If you can post your current (non-preferable) way of doing it, that would be very helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [c#: a method to count occurrences in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/c-a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Linq to compute frequencies, e.g.:

```
List<String> source = new List<string>() {
  "Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "Hi", "Hello"
};

Dictionary<String, int> freqs = source
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(item => item.Key,
                item => item.Count());

....
int freqHi = freqs["Hi"]; // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of occurrences of a certain element in a list, you can simply do:

```
List.Count(x => x == "Hi");
```

**EDIT:** If you just want an short-hand way of telling which element occurs N times, you could accomplish that with a nested query:

```
List<string> greetings = new List<string> {"Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "Hello", "Hi"};

List<string> greetingsThatOccurThreeTimes = greetings
    .Where(s1 => greetings.Count(s2 => s1 == s2) == 3).ToList();
```

**EDIT #2**: You could also clean this up by using extension methods.

By declaring this:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> WithNOccurrences<T>(this List<T> source, int n)
    {
        return source.Where(s1 => source.Count(s2 => s1.Equals(s2)) == n).ToList();
    } 
}
```

You could do something like this in your calling code:

```
List<string> greetings = new List<string> {"Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "Hello", "Hi"};

// This list will only contain "Hi" (but 3 times, though)
List<string> greetingsThatOccurThreeTimes = greetings.WithNOccurrences(3);
```

This should more closely resemble your "ThreeOfAKind == true".

If you only want to get back one of each item that occurs N times, simply add `.Distinct()` to the extension method, like so:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> WithNOccurrences<T>(this List<T> source, int n)
    {
        return source
            .Where(s1 => source.Count(s2 => s1.Equals(s2)) == n)
            .Distinct().ToList();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well, what I was thinking is something like there are 3 hi's in the list and 2 hellos. We want to count the multiples of those items. These items may work in a list.GroupBy<> function, however I was wondering if there was a way where we could have "threeofAkind = true" when we iterate through the list and find three of the "hi" in the list.

Comment: I have added an extension method which does just about that. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I am relatively new to coding and let's just say college doesn't exactly teach us things like this.

Comment: I don't think you'd **want** college teaching you stuff like this - it's not really that important from a fundamentals perspective. You pick these little "extra's" up along the way. Don't forget to accept the answer that you think answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

This Linq Query will give you the list of items which have duplicates

```
 var mutiples = l.GroupBy(e => e).Where(c=>c.Count()>1);
```

you can iterate over the mutiples list using this code

```
 foreach (var pair in mutiples)
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " " + pair.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
        public List<string> GetDuplicates(List<string> list)
        {
            var q = from s in list
                    group s by s into g
                    select new { str = g.Key, count = g.Count() };

            return q.Where(str => str.count > 1).Select(str => str.str).ToList<string>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string words = "Hi, Hi, Hello, Hi, Hello";
var countList = words.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
int count = countList.Where(s => s.Contains("Hi")).Count();
```

count = 3 when running this code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group them first, and then perform a selection operation. If you are asking to count them, an example can be:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>{ "hi", "hi", "hi", "hello" };
stringList.GroupBy(i => i).Select(i => new {i.Key, i.ToList().Count }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812657/1339616

You can also use the LINQ query syntax like this.

```
from    s in new List<string> {"Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "Hi", "Hello"}
group   s by s into g
where   g.Count() > 1
orderby g.Count() descending
select  new {Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```