# How to left join to another left join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by

I have a table that holds stock items. These stock items have the following properties

```
public class StockItem
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
}
```

Where StoreId can be either 1 (**Store A**) or 2 (**Store B**)

I want to group these items to get the following result

```
BrandId
ModelId
Count in Store A
count in Store B
```

I have used `group by` clause before but not in this way. How should I write the linQ statement to accomplish my task?

To summarize I have the following records

```
Id   BrandId   ModelId   Price   StoreId
=========================================
1       1         1       11        1
2       1         1       11        1
3       1         2       12        1
4       1         2       12        2
5       1         1       11        2
```

and trying to get the following result

```
BrandId   ModelId   CountInStoreA   CountInStoreB
=================================================
    1        1            2               1
    1        2            1               1
```

Comment: I think you can find more info suitable to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448203/linq-to-sql-using-group-by-and-countdistinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = from item in db.Items
          group item by new { item.BrandId, item.ModelId, item.TotalPrice }
          into gr
          select new 
          {
              gr.Key.BrandId,
              gr.Key.ModelId,
              gr.Key.TotalPrice,
              CountA = gr.Count(it => it.StoreId == 1),
              CountB = gr.Count(it => it.StoreId == 2),
          }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But what if I were using multiple tables with inner and outer joins and I needed to group with parameters from multiple tables/objects at the same time?

Comment: @user4591106 Please, update your question in explain in details your scenario.

Comment: Working more on the subject and making extensive search I have found a solution for the next question. But I appreciate your intention on further help. Thank you very much.