# SQL to LINQ Convertion error: DISTINCT an Agregate count cannot be converted to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL query and I am trying to convert it to LINQ. But when I do so, I am getting this error:

> SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: DISTINCT an Agregate count cannot be converted to LINQ

```
SELECT 
ST_CN_NO,
DN_DT,
count(ST_CN_NO) as totlines,
count(distinct LOC_CODE) as totloc,
sum(SN_QTY)as totscnqty,
sum(SAP_QTY) as totmpqty
from physical_count 
where 1=1  
group by ST_CN_NO,DN_DT  
order by physical_count.ST_CN_NO
```

So, how can I convert `count(distinct LOC_CODE)` to LINQ? Is there any way to do so?

This is my LINQ query whithout adding `count(distinct LOC_CODE)`:

```
from t in db.PHYSICAL_COUNT
where
  1 == 1
group t by new {
  t.ST_CN_NO,
  t.DN_DT
} into g
orderby
  g.Key.ST_CN_NO
select new {
  ST_CN_NO = (Int32?)g.Key.ST_CN_NO,
  g.Key.DN_DT,
  totlines = (Int64?)g.Count(),
  totscnqty = (Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.SN_QTY),
  totmpqty = (Int32?)g.Sum(p => p.SAP_QTY)
}
```

Comment: I think `totloc = g.Select(p => p.LOC_CODE).Distinct().Count();` would work.  However I doubt it gets translated back to the same SQL.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that, fixed it.

Comment: Is there a reason for the WHERE clause? It seems to do nothing in the SQL and in the LINQ.

Comment: @AndyNichols If I had to guess that SQL was generated by something that dynamically added clauses, and the `1=1` was just a default clause for when none are added.

Comment: BTW what exactly is giving you that error?  I assume it's some type of SQL to Linq converter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL using GROUP BY and COUNT(DISTINCT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448203/linq-to-sql-using-group-by-and-countdistinct)

Comment: I get it in Linqer