# Count of each unique value in a list

Tags: vb.net

I need to find the unique values from a list and the number of times each value occurred in the original list. Here is what i have so far:

```
Dim Lister As New List(Of String)()

For Each item In eColumn
    Lister.Add(item.value)
Next

Dim Result As New List(Of String)
Result = Lister.Distinct().ToList

For Each st In Result
    MsgBox(st)
Next
```

The result is a list of all the unique values, but does not include a count for each item. For example, if my list was

```
John
John
Abbey
Larry
Larry
Larry
Charles
```

I want 4 values returned: John = 2, Abbey = 1,Larry = 3, Charles = 1.

Comment: [It does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @GSerg please explain

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I am pulling my values from an excel column

Comment: Follow the linq in comment 1

Comment: @Plutonix I don't understand the link... I dont see where it says how  I get a count of each unique item?

Comment: If `results` is a `List(Of String)` holding the unique items then, as the link clearly explains `results,Count` will be the number of unique items

Comment: Near duplicate of [LINQ to SQL using GROUP BY and COUNT(DISTINCT)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449930/2592875)

Comment: @Plutonix You're missing what I am looking for.  I need the count of how many of those items per value are in my list.

Comment: @Plutonix so if John is in the list two times, i need the number 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using linq's .Distinct() is only going to give you a list containing each distinct name in your list; so as you must have seen when your messagebox loop ran, it just shows you each name that is in your list once.

VB's lists do not have a native function for returning the count of an item's occurrences in a list, so to achieve your desired result just group them using linq's .GroupBy() function. It will return a Linq.GroupedEnumerable object, which can be iterated through and also possesses the kind of count property you're looking for:

```
    Dim myList As New List(Of String) From {"John", "John", "Abbey", "Larry", "Larry", "Larry", "Charles"}

    Dim groupedNames = myList.GroupBy(Function(x) x)
    If groupedNames IsNot Nothing AndAlso groupedNames.Count > 0 Then
        For Each person In groupedNames
            Debug.Print(person.Key & "-" & person.Count.ToString)
        Next
    End If
```

Output:

```
John-2
Abbey-1
Larry-3
Charles-1
```

Comment: Can you explain where the OP is having issues? Posting a solution that's doesn't explain why their code doesn't work isn't helpful...