# GROUP BY+distinct record count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Please consider these data:

```
Id        StateCode           PersonCode           Feature1
-----------------------------------------------------------
1             1                 2000                 10          
2             1                 2000                 13      
3             1                 3000                 20      
4             2                 2000                 1      
5             2                 2000                 13      
6             2                 4000                 10      
7             2                 4000                 11      
8             2                 5000                 10      
9             2                 5000                 1      
10            3                 2000                 10      
11            3                 3000                 9      
12            3                 3000                 1      
13            3                 3000                 4
```

I want to get this result that come from `distinct StateCode & PersonCode`

```
Count       StateCode
  2            1
  3            2
  2            3
```

and I wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count,aa.StateCode
FROM   
     (select distinct StateCode, PersonCode
      from @tbl) aa
GROUP BY aa.StateCode
```

How I can write this query with one query and group by?

and if possible how I can write this query with one `LINQ` query?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the expected output.  Can you explain it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query - Selecting COUNT(\*) with DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521605/sql-server-query-selecting-count-with-distinct)

Comment: Why is there C# and Linq tag?  What is this question about ? It a combinaison of 2 duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448203/linq-to-sql-using-group-by-and-countdistinct

Comment: The first one found using your title the second one adding Linq to your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the query as :-

```
select count(distinct PersonCode) , StateCode from @tbl group by StateCode ;
```

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: use `count(distinct PersonCode)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If your DB server supports window functions, then here is a solution:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33986d/3

```
SELECT DISTINCT StateCode, COUNT(DISTINCT PersonCode) OVER (PARTITION BY StateCode) AS "Count" from @tbl ORDER BY StateCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try GroupBy

```
class StateCodeCount
{
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public int StateCode {get; set;}
}

var result = datatableStateCode
    .GroupBy(c => c.StateCode )
    .Select(c => new StateCodeCount
    {
        StateCode = c.Key,
        Count= x.Where(g => g.StateCode== c.Key)
                .Select(t => t.PersonCode)
                .Distinct()
                .Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(DISTINCT PersonCode) , StateCode from @tbl group by StateCode ;
```

DISTINCT COUNT(*) will return a row for each unique count. What you want is [COUNT(DISTINCT *expression*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx): evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521656/2750968