# Selecting Distinct Count and Sum of columns received as sub-query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to get summarized data for a report that shows total amount & suppliers Count per decision in entity Framework Syntax. My Result needed to include a SUM of Amount and COUNT of total suppliers per decision.

I have a table of suppliers with the following columns:

`SupplierNo | Decision | DecisionIssuedOn | Amount | SupplierGroup | SubSupplier`

Raw SQL query to get above data for a specific time period is:

```
SELECT S.Decision, SUM(S.Amount) AS TotalAmount, COUNT(DISTINCT S.SupplierNo) AS SupplierCount
FROM (SELECT * FROM Indentors WHERE Indentors.DecisionIssuedOn BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31') S
GROUP BY S.Decision
```

Which gives data as:

```
     SupplierCount | Amount 
     -----------------------
Approved     20 |  5000

Rejected     11 |  3000

In-Process   5  |  1500
```

Now from front end, the condition parameters can be anything from the given pool of options (dropdowns) which when selected add where clause in the exixting query like

`WHERE Decision = 'Approved' AND SupplierGroup ='ABC' AND SubSupplier ='zxc'`

The problem is I am having a hard time getting the desired result using Entity Framework lambda expressions instead of raw SQL.

What I did so far:

I checked for the availability of Options from fornt-end to build where clause as:

```
IQueryable<Supplier> suppliers = this.db.suppliers.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id);


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedSupplierGroup) == false)
            {
                suppliers = suppliers.Where(i => i.SupplierGroup == selectedSupplierGroup);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedSubSupplier) == false)
            {
                suppliers = suppliers.Where(i => i.SubSupplier == selectedSubSupplier);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedDecision) == false)

            {
                suppliers = suppliers.Where(i => i.Decision == selectedDecision);
            }

            if (selectedDecisionIssuedOn.HasValue)

            {
                suppliers = suppliers.Where(i => i.DecisionIssuedOn >= selectedDecisionIssuedOn);
            }

              var result = suppliers
                        .GroupBy(i => i.Decision)
                        .Select(i => i.SupplierNo).Distinct().Count(); // Gives me error
```

The error is:

> IGrouping  does not contain a definition for SupplierNo, and no extension method blah blah blah...

But after that I am unable to get data as the raw query (described above) would get me. Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? Please provide as much information as you can :)

Comment: Updated question with error message I am getting.

Comment: Similar question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448203/linq-to-sql-using-group-by-and-countdistinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a similar result to your SQL query. Give it a try and see how you get on:

```
var results = suppliers
    .Where(i => i.DecisionIssuedOn >= selectedDecisionIssuedOn)
    .GroupBy(i => i.Decision)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Decision = group.Key,
        TotalAmount = group.Sum(g => g.Amount),
        SupplierCount = group.Select(i => i.SupplierNo).Distinct().Count()
    });
```

Comment: Sure, let me give it a try

Comment: Can you please explain: In your answer, do I still have to use .Where(i=> i.DecisionIssuedOn) ... because where clause is being created dynamically in the code.

Comment: @Programmer No, you can remove the Where if you're going to do it above.

Comment: That seems promising. Thank you for assistance.